# Flutter-Hive, put on specific key after register class

Tags: flutter, class, dart, hive

I registerd model.dart / model.g.dart also opened box in main().
I just only want to put value on 'userName', don't want effect other key/ value
but how?

[image]

[image]

> on main

[image]

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do this u will have to first get the object for the model as based on your criteria this object already exists with different data!.

u can create a copyWith fn in your Model to mutate the object(clone).

u can achieve this using something as follows

```dart
 final box = await Hive.openBox('db');

// the returned value can be null here, i assumed that the data already exists
final existingValue = box.get('userName');

await box.put('userName', existingValue.copyWith(userName: textController.text));
```

Comment: I got error with using 'get' and 'put' method, it says "the method 'get' isn't defined for the type 'Future'." btw thanks for the answer

Comment: @Hajongmyeong make sure u await!, it would be great if u can add a gist to provide more context so its faster to help you on (=

Comment: solved with putAt(). thanks for help  :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved with putAt()

> code

```
    var dataBox = Hive.box<DataModel>('db');
    ...
    DataModel data = DataModel(
                index: dataBox.length,
                ingredientName: reactiveController.selectedIcon.value,
                userSpecIngredientName: ingname.text,
                shelfLife: shelfLife,
                memo: ingmemo.text);
    dataBox.putAt(index, data);
```